# categories not showing suite commerce advanced netsuite

Tags: categories, netsuite, suitecommerce

We are in the process of setting up our new website with Suite Commerce Advance - this means that we have been moving items around in categories, we seem to have an issue where items are disappearing within the categories (they are still present on the website if you search from them) has anyone else had this problem and how do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

i hope the problem was already solved, for other folks facing the same.
follow the following step:

1. Check whether the categories are properly tagged in commerce categories.
2. Check the display in webstore checkbox to be true.
3. Inside Webstore tab -> WebSite categories-> Site category = Home.
4. Then build index and cache invalidation request. Not always
      mandatory(but if any thing changes in record level).